# Chrome refused to load a script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

lately i create a chrome extension to cast videos to chromecast its was working fine but now stopped working and its shows this error.

> Refused to load the script 'chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/cast_sender.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com".

Error in browser console :

[image]

Here the manifest

```
{
   "background": {
      "page": "html/background.html"
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "images/download_inactive.png",
      "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
      "default_title": "extension name"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "js/contentscript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com; object-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com;",
   "description": "extension description",
   "icons": {
      "128": "images/logo.png"
   },

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "extension name",
   "permissions": [ "cookies","activeTab", "tabs","proxy", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "storage", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "2.0.9",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "*" ],
   //"options_page": "html/options.html"
   "options_ui": {
      "page": "html/options.html",
      "open_in_tab": false
   }
}
```

Comment: OK, I'm not into writing extensions or manifests for them but I noticed `https://www.gstatic.com` returns a 404. I don't know if that will really impact the security policy, though - as I understand `script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com` means both `self` and the URL are acceptable. It also appears that you'd get that error if a scripts will try to be executed from a different domain.

Comment: The problem is loading this: chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/cast_sender.js and this is not allowed in you CSP. Is this script (cast_sender.js) being loading remotelly?

Comment: @f-bernal yes this script was loaded remotely, so any idea how to make chrome load this chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/cast_sender.js

what should i add to CSP